# Where is stored information from YARN applications AWS EMR (Application history)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

**Context**

I run spark applications on an Amazon EMR cluster.

These applications are orchestrated by Yarn.

I didn't define `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs`, `spark.yarn.historyServer.address` or other configurations.
In Application history tab there is information about 'steps'.

I looked to [official documentation (View Application History)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-cluster-application-history.html), but didn't find an information where is "Application history" stored.

**Question**

I would like to know where is "Application history" stored by default.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD**
The main problem is that the cluster is off and I can't look on master node

Comment: Did you try to use spark history on master_node:18480 or yarn ui for that on master_node:8088?

Comment: @dytyniak I'm sorry, I forgot to say that cluster is shot down

Comment: Please try to follow this instruction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html. You should configure an archiving to the s3 bucket.